# php search script returns same result

Tags: php

I have some output problems with my search script - regardless of search term, i always get same output result. My echoed query seems to be alright, but i always get the same result as output. This is my script:

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
if($_GET['search'] == "search"){
$loop = "";
$search = !empty($_GET['find']) && ($_GET['find'] != "")?strip_tags($_GET['find']):false;
$search = trim($search);
$field = !empty($_GET['field'])?strip_tags($_GET['field']):false;
$field = trim($field);

if ($search == ""){
    echo "Please enter search conditions !";
}
elseif ($search != ""){
echo "<u>Searched term</u>:"." ".$search."<br />"."<u>In</u>:"." ".$field."<br/><br/>";
$sql = "SELECT p_url FROM papers";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$condition = array();

if ($field == "author"){
$condition[] = "WHERE p_authors LIKE '%$search%'";
}   
if ($field == "papername"){
$condition[] = "WHERE p_name LIKE '%$search%'";
}
if ($field == "coauthors") {
$condition[] = "WHERE p_cauthor LIKE '%$search%'";
}
if ($field == "abstract"){
$condition[] = "WHERE p_abstract LIKE '%$search%'";
}
if ($field == "keywords"){
$condition[] = "WHERE p_abstract LIKE '%$search%'";
}

$sql .= " ".implode(" ", $condition);
echo "$sql"."<br />";
$out = mysql_num_rows($query);
$result = "";

if ($out){
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      foreach ($result as $val){
         echo "$val"."<br />";
      }
  }
}
}
```

Any suggestions ? Thx

Comment: Additional to the misplaced `mysql_query()`: Since `$field` can have only one of the values, you do not need the array and the `implode()`, and the `if`s can be replaced by a `switch`. And please inform yourself about SQL injection, which is a serious vulnerability in your script. And the PHP mysql extension is deprecated and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0, better use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Yeah, now i see misplaced query, thx, ill look into mentioned injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your $query variable after you add the conditions to the $sql variable. Right now you simply execute the query without any condition.

Comment: 2 hours goes through waste :S. Thank you, that solved it.